# Alert message validation - Test Automation (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

Good Morning! I'm catching a lot in a setting. Could you help me?

Scenario: I perform an action. It is a temporary (alert) message on the screen. After a few seconds, disappear! What I need: Perform a message validation on this temporary alert.

Below is the location of the element:

```
<div id = "alert-message-20190726103017" class = "top alert danger alert alert fired";>
<button type = "button" class = "close"/button>
<i class = "fa-exclamation icon"/i>
"Invalid username and password"/div>
```

Can someone help me? Please and thanks!

Comment: When you say temporary, does this mean the element is still in the dom, but not visible or that it is removed from the html altogether when no longer needed?

Comment: That's not valid HTML. Please update your question with the actual HTML.

Comment: Guys, very thanks for the feedbacks!!! It worked!!!!! Gratitude!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try wait alert message will be visible and get text using `WebDriverWait` and `visibilityOfElementLocated` condition:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
String alertMessage = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
       .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".top.alert.danger.fired"))).getText();
```

If alert message not disappear on hover, you can try `Actions` and `moveToElement` to hover and then get text and close alert by click on close button:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement alertMessageElement = wait
   .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".top.alert.danger.fired")));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(alertMessageElement).perform();
String alertMessage = alertMessageElement.getText();

alertMessageElement.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.close")).click();
```